# jQuery Selection Issue

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, selector

Im currently writing some form validation with jQuery and having the followin problem..

I give ids to my inputs in such a way that when data is posted, i have an array to work with like so..

```
<input type="text" id="user[name]" />
<input type="text" id="user[email]" />
```

This means that when the data is posted to my script, i will have a "user" arrau available so i can do things like `$user["name"]`however, when i try to select the inputs with jquery by doing..`var name = $("#user[name]")` it wont work. But if i just have the id of the input as "username" then `var name = $("#username")` will work.

Im assuming its to do with CSS selectors in jquery as it things im trying to access a user object with an ID of name? like the way `$("input[username]")` would select an input with the id of username.

Any ideas on how i can get around this? And would it work in all browsers?

Comment: What's going on with id="user[name]"? Do you want the id to be literally the string "user[name]" or do you want something more complicated than that?

Comment: having the id="user[name]" results in a nice array when input is passed to script.

Comment: use name="user[name]" and id="user_name" or sthg different generated. I think [] are not usable as ID values. Further CSS uses [] in selectors for attribute filtering, so its wrong too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` value of a form element is not what gets passed to the server, it is only used internally by the document DOM and scripting languages.  It is the `name` that gets passed.

Your form elements need to be altered to something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="user[name]" />
<input type="text" id="useremail" name="user[email]" />
```

The [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) addresses the proper naming of elements:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

Using square brackets in the `name` attribute is a common technique to pass data in an array format to the server side scripting language, but using them in an `id` will certainly confuse JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely surprised that the selector doesn't work, because your IDs are not valid according to the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
> letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
> by any number of letters, digits
> ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
> ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
> (".").

The PHP manual has a tutorial on the correct way to [pass form elements as an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) to the server, using the `name` attribute rather than the ID:

```
<input name="MyArray[keyOne]" />
<input name="MyArray[keyTwo]" />
<input name="MyOtherArray[]" />
<input name="MyOtherArray[]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
$("[id='user[name]']")
$("#user\\[name\\]")
$("#user\\005Bname\\005D")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all know that the name attribute is what gets posted and not the id.

Now to the issue

to access `<input type="text" id="user[name]" />` with jQuery you need to do it like this

```
var name = $("input[id='user[name]']");
```